# 403 Error when trying to run Vagrant Up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Been trying to get this Django project running for over a week now, but have had absolutely no luck what-so-ever. Am now trying to run it via vagrant, but am now having problems with that. If anyone can provide any assitance, I will be extremely appreciative. I am just trying to get Vagrant up and running, but am getting a 403 Forbidden error. I'm running on a windows 8 machine.

Here is my output:
[image: vagrant ouput]

and here is my vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "nice-env.sh"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Here is my provision.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Directory of the Django project
BASEDIR=/vagrant
# The apache user
WEBUSER=vagrant
SERVERNAME=192.168.33.10
SQLROOTPASS=6zXAHftMRFGhn4DsYfdsH6dw
DBNAME=cfmt
DJANGOUSER=cfmt
DJANGOPASS=CesVoucrud

debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password $SQLROOTPASS"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password $SQLROOTPASS"

apt-get update
apt-get install -y git apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi python python-pip python-dev mysql-client mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev

pip install virtualenv

echo Setting up virtualenv
cd $BASEDIR && virtualenv venv
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    VENV=$BASEDIR/.venv
else
    echo NOTE: Windows does not allow symlinks in the /vagrant directory, so virtualenv has been installed in /var/cfmt-venv
    cd /var && virtualenv cfmt-venv
    VENV=/var/cfmt-venv
fi
echo Installing python dependencies using pip
$VENV/bin/pip install -r $BASEDIR/requirements.txt

# Fix weird module location issue
ln -s $BASEDIR $BASEDIR/../cfmt

echo Installing settings_local.py
cat > $BASEDIR/settings_local.py <<EOL
# Fix weird module location issue
import sys
sys.path.append("$BASEDIR/..")

DEBUG = True

# If sqlite3 doesn't cut it, we may need to switch the dev env back to MySQL,
# and solve the from-scratch migration issues
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
#         'NAME': '$DBNAME',
#         'USER': '$DJANGOUSER',
#         'PASSWORD': '$DJANGOPASS',
#     }
# }
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': '$BASEDIR/database.sqlite'
   }
}

MEDIA_URL = 'http://192.168.33.10/media/'
EOL

echo Updating apache site
cat > /etc/apache2/sites-available/cfmt.conf <<EOL
WSGIDaemonProcess webclient user=$WEBUSER group=$WEBUSER threads=25 python-path=$BASEDIR:$BASEDIR/..:$VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup webclient
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / $BASEDIR/sites/cfmt/conf/cfmt.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath $BASEDIR

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName $SERVERNAME

    DocumentRoot $BASEDIR/media
    <Directory $BASEDIR/media>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory $VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /adminmedia/ $VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
    Alias /media/ $BASEDIR/media/
    Alias /static/ $BASEDIR/media/

</VirtualHost>
EOL
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled && ln -s -f ../sites-available/cfmt.conf 100-cfmt.conf
rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default*
a2dismod autoindex
service apache2 restart

if [ ! -f /var/db-inited ]
then
    echo Initializing database
    mysql -uroot -p$SQLROOTPASS <<EOL
    CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8;
    CREATE USER '$DJANGOUSER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$DJANGOPASS';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on $DBNAME.* TO '$DJANGOUSER'@'localhost';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on test_$DBNAME.* TO '$DJANGOUSER'@'localhost';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOL
    touch /var/db-inited
fi

echo Creating upload directories
#mkdir -p $BASEDIR/static/uploads
#chown -R $WEBUSER:$WEBUSER $BASEDIR/static/uploads

echo Running syncdb
$VENV/bin/python $BASEDIR/manage.py syncdb --noinput
echo Running migrations
$VENV/bin/python $BASEDIR/manage.py migrate
echo Seeding model fixtures
$VENV/bin/python $BASEDIR/manage.py loaddata $BASEDIR/fixtures/cfmt.json
```

Comment: did you try to retrieve the file (url) before that 403? couldn't it just be that the file returns a 403?

Comment: It's probably something in one of your provisioning shells. I would try adding a `sudo apt-get update` before doing any `apt-get install` (like the above). If that doesn't fix it, could you post your provision.sh contents as well?

Comment: I agree with BrianC the vagrant script even suggests this after the 403 line!

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get update and apt-get install, but still receiving same errors.

Comment: Not sure why, but it was trying to search for a .venv (hidden on linux) folder which was only a file on my windows machine. There was also a venv folder in the same directory. I removed the .venv file and renamed the venv folder to .venv, and am no longer getting any errors with Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the issue isn't with vagrant but with something in the provisioning script or in the machine configuration. This is hard to say as I don't have the script but I would start looking there, specifically if it is editing the apt updates list or something. I would also check into version requirements, it could be too new for Ubuntu 12.04 which is what your basebox is running.

Comment: I've added my provision.sh file contents, not sure what is wrong with it however.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with the comments on the main question -- I think the base box isn't playing well with apt get. I would just stand up a vanilla VM and run your apt-get installs one at a time to see what happens.